# How to Isolate a list of records that don't exist in the database

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying select from the database 4000+ records and I realize that 800 of them are not in the database.

The following query returns three rows (emails) and only one of them is not on the database yet, is there a way I can get a list of those not on the database ?

`SELECT 
    email
FROM
    email_list
WHERE
    email IN ('email1@test.com', 
              'email2@test.com',
              'email3@test.com',
              'email4@test.com');`

Thanks

Comment: And why doesn't your query work?

Answer (score 0):

Use `NOT EXIST` in your where clause:

```
...WHERE NOT EXISTS (query_to_get_the_unwanted_records)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Mysql Function EXIST or Not EXIST

sample query:

```
SELECT *
FROM customers
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT *
              FROM order_details
              WHERE customers.customer_id = orders.customer_id);

SELECT *
FROM customers
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                  FROM order_details
                  WHERE customers.customer_id = orders.customer_id);
```

Comment: It doesn't work for my query since I have a comma separated list to test.